# What does aesthetic mean?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I would like to comprehend the meaning of the word *aesthetic*. 
For some context

> ***Aesthetically*** pleasing work.

How do I use this word? How do I use *esthetic* in a sentence. I have consulted the oxford dictionary.

Comment: Can you edit into your post what the dictionary told you, and why you're still confused?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The noun *[aesthetic](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/aesthetic_2)* refers to a quality or aspect of something which appeals to the senses. The plural form *aesthetics* refers to multiple of these aspects, or to the [philosophy of beauty](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/beauty/) in general.

For example, to describe the *aesthetic* of a house is to appreciate its form, as opposed to considerations like its price or construction. To debate the *aesthetic* of a poem is to argue about how pleasing it sounds, as opposed to its symbolic depth or its literary impact.

To call something *aesthetically pleasing* is in essence to call it beautiful, i.e. pleasing to the senses, but particularly the senses of sight and hearing— it would be unusual to describe a delicious meal or an aromatic perfume so. One might contrast something which is *aesthetically pleasing* with something which is *intellectually pleasing*, for example— something which may be clever, or mathematically elegant, or rich in cultural references, but may not evoke a visceral sensory appreciation.